# What's the word for "the kind of very close relationship between friends that feels like one involving family/relatives"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the word for "the kind of very close relationship between friends that feels like one involving family/relatives"? It's something ending with "-ish", and can be used in this kind of sentence:

> "I'm having a ***************-ish dinner with them".

In other words, it's a kind of dinner with very close friends that you consider family.

Comment: Well, there's "sisterhood" and "brotherhood" among same-sex comrades; and "camaraderie" among a group of friends of either or both sexes. One speaks of "bonding" (and of "soulmates", although this usuallly applies to a pair of lovers, not just close friends.)

Comment: Maybe *I'm inviting John over for a **brotha-from-anotha-motha** dinner*.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your friends are more like brothers or sisters to you than they are like grandparents, so "brotherly", "sisterly", or "fraternal" work, although none of them end with -ish.

Answer (score 0):

If the emphasis is on relaxed enjoyment, rather than the familial aspect (why assume that family dinners are enjoyable?!), then I would use "**cosy**", or (as a German word which has also acquired currency in English) "**gemütlich**".

Answer (score 0):

The term [Frenemy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/frenemy) is well known, I'd suggest the opposite: 
[Framily](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/framily)

"I'm having a framily dinner with them".

Comment: Hello, Sam. But _frenemy_ can mean 'a person who is an enemy, masquerading as a friend'. Your suggestion would be confusing: people would have to guess a meaning for this non-lexical item.

Answer (score 0):

For your particular use case, "family"-ish, "private"-ish or maybe even "tight"-ish could work well. I'm unconvinced that any of those constitutes proper usage though, and would rather go with either a "close dinner" or a "private dinner."